# How do I make some text editable by an admin in a Vue app?

Tags: vue.js

I have created a website for a hobby project using Vue. The website features small text sections, and I would like for my collaborators - who are not familiar with any sort of coding - to be able to edit parts of the text using something like a WYSIWYG editor accessible by eg. an admin password.

What is the simplest way to make the text editable? I'm not asking for guidance on how to make a login section for the admins, rather I'm asking if it is easiest to for instance save the text in a database.

Basically my goal is to make a very small scale CMS using Vue, I guess

Comment: If you are using a reverse proxy like nginx then adding `HTTP Basic Authentication` to the proxy for a specific `/admin/` path would be the easiest approach. But you should really give more info about what you expect in your question, and what you've tried. Else there are enough tutorials on the web on how to implement authentication in vue.

Comment: It's not clear what you don't understand.  How to make editable text?  How to save data?  Whether you should use a database?